# How do I get a value from a user inside a visualforce page controlled by the apex class.

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a piece of apex code and in order for the loop in it to work I need to get an input from a user rather than put the number in manually. How do I do that ? 
Here is the apex code:

```
 public String numbersgenerated {get;set;}
     public Integer userinput {get;set;}
     public Decimal largenum {get;set;}
     list<Number_Setting__c> cslist = [SELECT Largest_Number__c FROM Number_Setting__c];


public void  genumber(){
     userinput = 5; 

    do{
        if(cslist.size() >0)
        largeNum = cslist[0].Largest_Number__c;
        largeNum ++;

        for (Number_Setting__c updt : cslist){
            updt.Largest_Number__c = largeNum; 
            update updt; 
        }

         userinput --;

      } while(userinput >  0);
   }
}
```

and this is what the visualfroce page code looks like:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="GenerateNumber"  showHeader="false" title="Contact us">

<apex:form >    
<apex:commandButton value="Generatethenum" action="{!genumber}" status="status" styleClass="btn btn-default" />
  <br/>
  <h3>
  <apex:outputText value="{!largeNum}" />
  </h3>
  </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use apex:inputtext to get the user entered value

You can bind a variable to your apex:inputtext and when you execute your action ,salesforce makes sure to run the setter so that the value is available to you in backend apex from front end .

Here is how it works

```
<apex:inputtext value="{!userinput}" />
```

Also keep action as pagereference or void method

```
public pagereference populatenumber(){
   system.debug('USER INPUT NUMBER..'+userinput);
    ---
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks it gave me errors previously it's so simple after all that.  I'm already using a void method public void  genumber(){ unless you're talking about something i'm missing ?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: It was sometthing to do with assignment to S objects. but it's fixed now thank you

Comment: Also dont name your action methods with get appended it might confuse you with getters on the page .

Comment: @Greg - seconding Mohith -- action method names should indicate some action occurring on the server - save, clone, calculateX, goToNextStep, ...